# How to get video data from webRTC server in python

Tags: python, webrtc

I have a problem. I want to receive data from a **webRTC** server (C#) and process it on python but I can't see any example for it. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of your project but if your webrtc server can publish the incoming RTP streams to another RTP client like ffmpeg, then you can send it to this ffmpeg process and tinker with the incoming stream frames with python.

Maybe this SO answer helps you:

https://superuser.com/a/1129600/129090